# Problem with adding framework into project

Tags: iphone, ipad

Project  has been taken from SCM Repositories.

Some frameworks are showing in redColor :  so it seems its not add into project properly or deleted..

When i am trying to added a required framework its also show me in same red color text. has a framework name. Its means that i not added properly the framework to the project.

Can any one guide how to add the framework in this cases.

@thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are built in libraries. The red indicates that Xcode cannot find them. It's possible that your Xcode installed is messed up and needs to be reinstalled. Do other projects compile correctly?